# Screen Recording and Screen Capturing tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

I would merge [desktop-recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-recording) (x8) and [screen-recorder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-recorder) (x18) into [screen-capture](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) (x122).

After that, should we — per Daniel's suggestion — try to split up [screen-capture](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture) into more precise tags, i.e. move all [screenshot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) related questions away from it?

Comment: Screenshots and videos are *very* different kinds of things. We should break `screen-capture` up into two more specific tags...

Comment: Hm, you make a good point, but I haven't really seen the term "screen capture" used for screenshots yet (except for OS X). So would you suggest moving all screenshot questions from `[screen-capture]` to `[screenshot]`? I mean, that's not orthogonal to my request.. We could do this after the creation of the synonyms.

Comment: I just read the `screen-capture` tag wiki. They should just implement my ambiguous tag proposal, it's about time...

Comment: Right now we have two tags for creating videos from screens. After execution of this, we'll have 0. So I'm not sure we should do this first.